# How do I route off a module in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a module declared.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['donor.donation.DonationController']);
```

Here is the setup of the `DonationController`.

```
var donationModule = angular.module('donor.donation.DonationController', ['ngRoute']);
donationModule.config(['$routeProvider', DonationConfig]);
```

And here is the `DonationConfig`

```
var DonationConfig = function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/donor/donation',
  {
    resolve: {
      resolvedData: 'DonationControllerResolver'
    },
    controller: 'DonationController',
    templateUrl: 'js/donor/donation/Donation.html'
  });
};

module.exports = DonationConfig;
```

The `$routeProvider` in the `DonationConfig` is looking for the route `/donor/donation`, but when I go to `http://localhost:5000/donor/donation`, I get `Cannot GET /donor/donation`.  How do I route off a module?  There are no other routes defined for this app, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `Angular` was looking for `#` in the route.  When I went to `http://localhost:5000#donor/donation` then everything worked like it was supposed to work.